# Clustering algorithm on top of decision tree learner

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka

Basically, I want to randomly split the users into two groups, run one tree learner for each group, test the data of each user against those two trees and move the user to the other group if it fits better in the other tree. I want to repeat this process until there is no switching of users (from one group to another)

I intend to repeat the whole process almost 20 times.

Is it possible to do this in weka? If not, what would be the best way to proceed with this problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this out of the box with Weka. There are clustering algorithms and classification algorithms, but there are no algorithms that combine both.

You can always implement your own training algorithm, by extending [Classifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html) class.